# 60hz & 144hz dual monitor setup on Windows 7

Tags: multiple-monitors

At the moment I have got a dual monitor setup with both panels at 60hz.
I want to upgrade one of those monitors to a 144hz panel. But I heard a lot about both monitors capping at 60hz if I do that.

Can someone tell me if it is possible to have a dual monitor setup in which I can run 1 panel at 144hz and 1 panel at 60hz at the same time? And if it is possible, how would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't indicate what OS.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm currently running windows 7 os, considering to upgrade to 10. definately if needed for this.

Comment: Updated your question with all relevant information